# Set PasswordAuthentication to no, now can't log in on Linode server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linode

I was following this tutorial trying to set up keys so I can log in without a password
http://linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html

Problem is, I followed his instructions except, I generated the key locally, and unless you did exactly as he said, you lock yourself out, which I did (had the "oh crap" moment after I d/c).  Now I'm locked out.  Is there any way I can backdoor into the server to undo what I did or do I have to start over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Linode Control Panel](https://manager.linode.com/). You should be able to access the server with [Lish](http://library.linode.com/troubleshooting/using-lish-the-linode-shell) in order to edit the SSH server's configuration.